# Running different jobs on commits on different branches in Gitlab

Tags: deployment, yaml, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm trying to set up my `.gitlab-ci.yml` in a way that different stages get executed on commits on different branches.
I have a development, master and release branch.

I want a staging deploy to run on a commit on master and a full release on a commit to release.

I'm currently trying this:

```
stages:
  - deploy
  - release

deployToAWS:
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - bash deploy/AWSdeploy.sh

deployToLive:
  only:
    refs:
      - release
  stage: release
  script:
    - bash deploy/liveDeploy.sh
```

But this only runs when I commit on my master branch, and nothing happens when I commit to my release branch.

So how do I change my file to run the release stage on a commit to the release branch?

Comment: Please make your question explicit. What is your "ask"?

Comment: Added the "ask" that was in the middle of the question to the end again for clarity